# If I change RootPanel to RootLayoutPanel my browser omits sliders. Why?

Tags: java, gwt

When I have a lot of widgets-more then a page can display--the "new" way with

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add(w)
```

does not show sliders in my browser. With the "old" way

```
RootPanel.get().add(w)
```

it does. Why? I want to use the "modern" way (to use TabLayoutPanel) with the GWT layout classes but now I can't.

(My index.html starts with `<!doctype html>`).

EDIT: If I change to

```
RootLayoutPanel.get().add( new ScrollPanel( widget) );
```

it works! I don't know if this is the right way...

Answer (score 3):

They are mutually exclusive, `RootPanel` supports automatic re-sizing and automatic scroll bars at the browser level. For one example, if you put items in a table and add enough to make them go off the bottom of the screen, `RootPanel` will automatically add a scroll bar so you can get to the bottom elements, `RootLayoutPanel` won't, unless you put that element in a `ScrollPanel` and then it isn't the same as what `RootPanel` does.

`RootLayoutPanel` expects you to control all this manually. You can either have one of the other, but not both. You have to tie handlers to the `resize` events when using `RootLayoutPanel` to inform the `Layout` portion when to re-layout things.

The goal of `RootLayoutPanel` is to allow you to make web based applications that are more desktop like. It isn't supposed to be a replacement for `RootPanel`, and it isn't *better* or *worse* unless it supports or doesn't support what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I use LayoutPanels and SimplePanels for my main layout (attached to the RootLayoutPanel). For panels that may need scrollbars I just add the style:

```
.overflow {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

An example template is given below. I think having ScrollPanels instead of SimplePanels would be an equally valid approach, it just depends on which works best for your design / requirements.  I prefer to only have scrollbars where they're needed so  I use overflow: auto.

```
  <ui:style>
    .filterPanel {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    .overflow {
        overflow: auto;
    }
  </ui:style>
  <g:LayoutPanel styleName="ListLayoutPanel">
    <g:layer left="0px" width="300px">
      <g:SimplePanel ui:field="filterPanel" styleName="{style.filterPanel}" />
    </g:layer>
    <g:layer left="300px" right="500px">
      <g:SimplePanel ui:field="tablePanel" styleName="{style.overflow}"></g:SimplePanel>
    </g:layer>
    <g:layer width="500px" right="0px">
      <g:SimplePanel ui:field="detailPanel" styleName="{style.overflow}"/>
    </g:layer>
  </g:LayoutPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```